# Node.js - Display mongoDB documents with console.log (No Shell)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using a mongoDB server that is located on another machine. My question is how can I display all the documents that were found with console.log? Currently my main.js script is this:

```
// Connect to Mongo
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://10.254.17.115:27017/ExpressOrder', function(err, db) {

// Handle errors
assert.equal(null, err);
    // Insert data
    db.collection('ExpressOrder').insert({"SID":"24676637"});
    // Count data
    db.collection('ExpressOrder').find().count().then(function(numItems) {
        console.log(numItems); // Use this to debug
        callback(numItems);
    })
    // Display all data in db
    var found = db.collection('ExpressOrder').find();
    console.log(found); // Use this to debug
});
```

The data is properly inserted, and counts properly, but I just now need to know how do I display all the documents to the console with console.log.

Comment: [Use `print`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2335094/819651) instead of `console.log`

Comment: @LuísSoares Now it says `print` is undefined

Comment: forget it. you're in NodeJS.. that answer if for MongoDB console :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var found = db.collection('ExpressOrder').find();
found.each(function(err, doc) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    if (doc != null) {
        console.log(doc);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to see each individuial doc then try function **each()** bellow code

```
 var db = mongoUtil.getDb();
  db.collection( 'products' ).find(function(err, docs){
    if (err) throw err;
    docs.each(function(err, doc){
      if(err) return console.err(err);
            // Log document
            console.log(doc)
    });
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Express', products:result });
  });
```